# Using getline on a string

Tags: c++, string, delimiter, getline, counting

How can I use `getline()` to read words form a line that I have stored in a string?

For example:

```
char ch[100],w[20];
cin.getline(ch,100);
```

Now can I use `getline` to count the number of words in `ch`? I don't want to use a delimiter to directly count words from `ch`. I want to read words from `ch` and store them in `w`.

I have tried using `ch` in `getline` as a parameter.

Comment: Your title is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`getline` is implemented in the standard as either [a stream method](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=getline), or a `string` method which takes a stream: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

There is no standard implementation of `getline` which does not require a stream.

That said you can use `ch` to seed a `istringstream` to count the words in the string, but `basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& getline(basic_istream<CharT, Traits>&& input, basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str)` assumes a newline as the delimiter so that's not what you're going to want to count words. Similarly, a `getline` that takes a delimiter will only break on a specific character. Instead you could use [`basic_istream& basic_istream::operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) which will split words on all whitespace characters:

```
istringstream foo(ch);

for(auto i = 1; foo >> w; ++i) {
    cout << i << ": " << w << endl;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/SjiOvU)

---

Just as a note here, defining `char w[20]` is just begging for an out of bounds write. At a minimum you need to define that such that if `ch` is filled with non-whitespace characters, `w` can contain it all. You could do that by defining `char w[100]`.
But if someone were to come and increase the size of `ch` without changing the size of `w` and then you'd be in trouble again. In C++17 you could define `w` like this `char w[size(ch)]` prior to that you could do `char w[sizeof(ch) / sizeof(ch[0])]`
But your best option is probably to just make both `w` and `ch` `string`s so they can dynamically resize to accommodate user input.